# angular-ui bootstrap tab select function on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Am trying to call an expression function on tab select using angular ui bootstrap, however the expression is not being called but checking on angular inspector the function /expression exists : below is my code work:

NB : Other tabs function correctly

**Angular View**

```
<uib-tab ng-click="vm.alertMe" select="" heading="New Invoice">
                          .....
 </uib-tab>
```

**controller used as vm**

```
vm.alertMe = alertMe;

 function alertMe() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
            });
          }
```

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your questions. If you have an answer, post it below and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always inject the base service names you use in your angular app ,in the above example i was not calling : `$window` service which resulted in the bug / error .my final controller is as following :

```
function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.patients')
        .controller('PatientsController', PatientsController);

    PatientsController.$inject = ['$http','$window'];
    /* @nginject */
    function PatientsController($http, $window) { 
       vm.alertMe = function() {

             $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
           }
     }
}
```

and the view ,

```
<uib-tab  select="vm.alertMe()" heading="New Invoice">
                          .....
 </uib-tab>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not calling the function in your DOM.

instead of this:

```
<uib-tab ng-click="vm.alertMe" select="" heading="New Invoice">
```

you should be calling it like this:

```
<uib-tab ng-click="vm.alertMe()" select="" heading="New Invoice">
```

Comment: Please refer to above http://stackoverflow.com/a/34246855/1226748:  i was not calling  `$window ` service

Answer (score 0):

Why not define the alertMe function directly on the vm. I can not see your whole code. I assume it should work if you vm is correctly assigned as `this` in the controller. Also make sure in the html, your controller is correctly defined. Let me know :)

```
vm.alertMe = function() {
              setTimeout(function() {
               $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
              });
             }
```

Comment: I resolved this : I was not calling the `$window` service to the controller

Comment: Oh, you mean you forget to inject that ?

Comment: Oh yes kinda in a hurry to finish he app !