# Angular js open modal on tab select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

Id like to open a modal on tab select am using UI Bootstrap plugin components , everything seem to work  ie the tabs open but , the modal page does not seem to be called on selecting the last tab , below is my code :  All Controller function are being called as `vm`

**Controller**

```
     function tab_open_call (size) {

      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
         templateUrl: '/cashier/views/cashier.angular_components.modal',
         size: size

       });

   }
```

**View**

```
<uib-tabset>
   <uib-tab heading="Profile">
   </uib-tab>
   <uib-tab heading="Address">
   </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab select=" vm.tab_open_call" heading="Setting">
   </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

**Modal View**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
 </div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Something here</p>
</div>
```

Please help out ?

> RESOLVED : I SIMPLY RESOLVED THIS BY ADDING THE  $uibModal SERVICE TO THE CONTROLLER , WHICH WAS NOT BEING CALLED !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgotten the `size` parameter? Try:

```
<uib-tab select="vm.tab_open_call('md')" heading="Setting">
</uib-tab>
```

Comment: Still does not work , the tab does not seem to call function  see related question i asked http://stackoverflow.com/q/34246804/1226748